# FFMPEG “buffer queue overflow, dropping” Doing Concat of two Overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, concatenation

Ffmpeg generate error "buffer queue overflow, dropping" (and a bad result) when i try to Concat two Overlay.

Like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "color=black@0:s=1920x1080:r=25" -i "D:\Dev\FormaVeo\Chutier\bunny.mp4" -i "D:\Dev\FormaVeo\Chutier\bunny2.mp4" -filter_complex "[0][1:v]overlay=shortest=1,fifo[A];[0][2:v]overlay=shortest=1,fifo[B];[A][B]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" "D:\Dev\FormaVeo\FormaVeoExport/montage_laurent3/video.mp4"
```

Someone understand ?

Thanks

Information: this command is simplified to only show the problem (Senses is not the subject here)

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "color=black@0:s=1280x720:r=30,format=yuva420p"
       -i "in1.mp4" -i "in2.mp4" -filter_complex
      "[0]fifo[a];
       [1:v]trim=start=0:duration=64.6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280x720[video0];
       [2:v]trim=start=1.254328:duration=8.155469,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280x720[video1];
       [0][video0]overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1[pisteVideo0_video0];
       [a][video1]overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1[pisteVideo0_video1];
       [pisteVideo0_video0][pisteVideo0_video1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" "result.mp4"
```

(I've adapted your command at the ffmpeg forum)

It's the base stream (color) that is leading to frame drops because it's being requested by the 2nd overlay fairly late. FIFO filters inserted to avoid that.

Comment: YES PERFECT !!!!
I used FIFO but not on the input 0 !!!!
Very very Thanks Mulvya !!

Comment: You can't reuse filtergraph outputs twice. In my answer. [0] is used once for overlay and the fifo copy once.

Comment: Yes i have see that after better inspection :)
Thanks